# Laravel. How to find models which has specific latest related model

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.3.

A Package Model has many Step Models.
The Step Model has a column calls `status` whose type is tiny int and `created_at` column.
For example, a package `A`, has these steps:

- Oct. 18 10:00, status 1
- Oct. 19 09:00, status 2

And, a package `B`, has these steps:

- Oct. 19 08:00, status 1
- Oct. 19 09:00, status 2
- Oct. 19 10:00, status 3

Just like that, many packages, each of them has many steps.

`A`'s latest step's status is 2 and `B`'s is 3

My problem is, how to find Packages whose latest step status is 2? The expected result is a collection of packages, in this example, should contains `A`.

I have tried add this in my Package Model.

```
public function steps()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Step');
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->steps()->latest()->limit(1);
}
```

and query with

```
Package::whereHas('status', function ($q) {
    $q->where('status', 2);
})->get();
```

but can't get expected result.

What not expected is, if Packages Table has only 1 row, the Package `B`, expected result is an empty collection. But it return a collection contains `B`.

I have also tried update the status function in Package Model to

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Step')->latest();
}
```

but it still not work.

So, what is the right way? Huge thank to you.

Comment: I think you are close, you should try to add a whereDoesntHave status > 2 to your query... If you don't have any other answers, I'll try it tonight

Answer (score 1):

This is quite challenging. I couldn't think of a solution that you can achieve what you want by doing a single Eloquent query. However I found a way that gives you the result in two steps - *i.e. query + filter*.

But before that you need to add a scope to your `Package` model:

```
public function scopeOfStatus($query, $status)
{
    return $query->whereHas('steps', function($q) use ($status) 
    {
        $q->where('status', $status);   
    });
}
```

**Step 1:** Write a query that retrieves all packages with at least one step matching your given status:

```
$status = 1;
$packages = Package::with('steps')->ofStatus($status)->get();
```

**Step 2:** Filter the result to get only packages which their last step matches your given status:

```
$packages = $packages->filter(function($package) use ($status)
{
    return $package->steps->last()->status == $status;
});
```

The final result is a collection of all packages that their last step has `status == 1`

Comment: I have read many answers, all of which are get latest step of all packages first and then filter them. From that I think I have to get result more than one step. So, is it a wise choice to add another column calls current_step_id which links to the latest step to Package Table and update it manually when inserting new step to simplify this query?

Comment: That is also possible, but you have to always keep in mind that if an error happens during your manual update process, your data becomes inconsistent - i.e. package references to a wrong latest step.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$wantedStatus = 2;
$packages = Package::with(['steps', function($query){
    $query->latest();
}])->get();

$filtered = $packages->filter(function ($package) use ($wantedStatus) {
    return $package->stpes->last()->status == $wantedStatus;
});
```