# Query scope to get models where latest relation model fulfills conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the bikes whose latest (last added) related location is within a certain area. This should be done using the query scope `scopeBounding($query, $latNorth, $lonEast, $latSouth, $lonWest)` on the bike model. Each bike has many locations:

```php
public function locations()
{
      return $this->hasMany(Location::class);
}
```

What I have so far doesn't seem to work at all, as I don't know how to only check for the latest of the related locations.

```php
public function scopeBounding($query, $latNorth, $lonEast, $latSouth, $lonWest)
{
      return $query->whereHas('locations', function ($q) use ($latNorth, $lonEast, $latSouth, $lonWest)
      {
          $q->whereBetween('latitude', [$latNorth, $latSouth])
            ->whereBetween('longitude', [$lonWest, $lonEast]);
      });
}
```

The bikes that are returned have latest locations which don't meet the `whereBetween` condition.

Selecting the locations and not the associated bikes however works as expected:

```php
App\Location::whereBetween('latitude', [50, 50.2])->whereBetween('longitude', [11, 12])->get();
```

**UPDATE:**

The location model has longitude and latitude fields:

```php
$table->decimal('latitude', 8, 6);
$table->decimal('longitude', 9, 6);
```

The scope is used like this:

```php
$bounding_bikes = Bike::bounding($latNorth, $lonEast, $latSouth, $lonWest)->get();
```

[a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135511/laravel-how-to-find-models-which-has-specific-latest-related-model)

Comment: Please can you show the code where you're using the scope? Also, what field types are you using for the `latitude` and `longitude`?

Comment: @RossWilson I edited the post, although I don't think there is a problem, because the whereBetween works when used outside the whereHas (as shown above UPDATE). The main question is how do I check whether the **latest** related location meets the whereBetween conditions and not **any** previous location.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like getting a distance between two points of a particular bike and then you can do a filter on distance.

I assume here you would have locations table and lat and lng should be column in that table.

**This will calculate the distance in km**

```
public function scopeBounding($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude, $distance)
{
  $raw = \DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( locations.lat ) ) * cos( radians( locations.lng ) - radians('.$from_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( locations.lat ) ) ) ) ) AS distance');

  return $query->select($raw)->orderBy( 'distance', 'asc' )->having('distance', '<=', $distance)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't at all what I'd like to achieve. I want to get the **bikes** whose **latest** location is within a rectangular whose top left coordinates are defined by  `$latNorth, $lonEast` and bottom right `$latSouth, $lonWest`.

Comment: I think you want something like geo spatial. Could you please take a look here.   https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial  Its more an idea then answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I finally found looks really ugly to me, but I didn't find anything better:

```
public function scopeBounding($query, $latNorth, $lonEast, $latSouth, $lonWest)
{
      return $query->whereHas('locations', function ($q) use($latNorth, $lonEast, $latSouth, $lonWest) {
        $q->whereRaw('`locations`.`id` = (select `locations`.`id` from `locations` where `bikes`.`id` = `locations`.`bike_id` order by `created_at` desc limit 1)')
          ->whereBetween('latitude', [$latSouth, $latNorth])
          ->whereBetween('longitude', [$lonWest, $lonEast]);
      });
}
```

So I'd be happy for any ideas how to simplify this!